# Artifactory AQL - Groovy - http URL connection is giving me 200 and 403

Tags: java, groovy, artifactory, http-status-code-403, artifactory-query-lang

I have the following script code which is basically iterating over a JSON blob and using Artifactory (AQL query), I'm trying to find an artifact's properties stored in the Artifactory.

**myscript Groovy file**:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

if (args.length < 1) {
    println("Please provide a properties file.")
    println("Usage: groovy myscript.groovy properties.json")
    System.exit(1)
}

println args[0]

Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File(args[1])
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
    properties.load(it)
}

username = properties["ArtifactoryUsername"]
password = properties["ArtifactoryPassword"]
aqlUrl = properties["AqlUrl"]
repoRestUrl = properties["RepoRestUrl"]
repoName = properties["RepoName"]

//decodeBase64(String value);
//Once the properties are loaded for various variables, use JSON blob mapping file. Arg0 is the name of JSON mapping file.
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
File mappingFile = new File(args[0])
jsonMapping = jsonSlurper.parseText(mappingFile.text)

def list = jsonMapping.extension[0].rpm

auth = new MyAuthenticator()
auth.setUserPass(username, password)
Authenticator.setDefault(auth);  //this solves UNAUTHORIZED: Status code (401)  (Unauthenticated)
String userPass = "Basic " + username + ":" + password;

list.each { rpm ->
    println(rpm.name)

    url = new URL(aqlUrl)
    conn = url.openConnection()

    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", userPass);  

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST")
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    conn.doOutput = true

    def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.outputStream)
    // RpmName1, RpmName2, RpmName2, ..
    writer.write('items.find({"$and" : ' +
                      '[' +
                            '{"repo": "' + repoName + '"}, ' +
                            '{"name": {"$match" : "' + rpm.name + '*"}}' +
                      ']' +
                    '})')

    //writer.flush()
    writer.close()


    //println(conn.)
    println(rpm.name + " (connection response code was): " + conn.getResponseCode())
    //conn.disconnect()
    //System.sleep(500); // this doesn't work. upto 5000.
    //System.sleep(10000); though, 10 seconds returns 200 each time for connection response code
}
```

My **mapping** file looks like:

```
{
  "extension": [
    {
      "rpm": [
        {
          "name": "RpmName1",
          "belongsTo": {
            "level1_products": [
              "product1",
              "product2"
            ],
            "level2_products": [
              "Sigma"
            ],
            "sub-system": [
              "sub-system-A"
            ],
            "level3_Products": [
              "level3_AAA",
              "level3_BBB"
            ],
            "final_level": [
              "Colorado"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "RpmName2",
          "belongsTo": {
            "level1_products": [
              "product3",
              "product4"
            ],
            "level2_products": [
              "Platinum"
            ],
            "sub-system": [
              "sub-system-B"
            ],
            "level3_Products": [
              "level3_XXX",
              "level3_YYY",
              "level3_ZZZ"
            ],
            "final_level": [
              "California"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
         ....
          .....
         ..... more similar entries here
         ...
        }
       ]
      },
      {
      "zip": [
        {
          "name": "ZipName1",
          "belongsTo": {
            "level1_products": [
              "Zip_AA",
              "Zip_BB"
            ],
            "level2_products": [
              "Zip_level2_i",
              "Zip_level2_i"
            ],
            "final_level": [
              "UberZip_California", "UberZip_Colorado"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The **output** is coming as:

```
RpmName1
RpmName1 (connection response code was): 200
RpmName2
RpmName2 (connection response code was): 403
RpmName2
RpmName3 (connection response code was): 403
RpmName4
RpmName4 (connection response code was): 200
...
.....
i.e. mix of both 200 and 403 response code
...
......
```

When I'm setting sleep for more than 7 seconds `System.sleep(7000)` then I'm getting response code printed as 200 every time.

Anything less than 5 is flaky i.e. I get either 200 or 403 differently each time I run this script.

It seems like I'm not doing something right i.e. closing the connection properly, so I tried `disconnect() for connection` and `.close() for writing`  methods as well but nothing helped.

**Stack trace output** for 403:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://artifactory.prod.com:9085/artifactory/api/search/aql
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://artifactory.prod.com:9085/artifactory/api/search/aql
```

Comment: Why you are not reading the response?

Comment: That'll simply print either `Forbidden` or `OK`. I'll update the post with the stacktrace output while getting 403

Comment: What are you seeing in Artifactory logs? 
request.log, access.log, and artifactory.log?